# python logging:How multiple handlers Can write to a single dynamic log file

Tags: python, logging

For a python project, I have a python log config file with multiple file handlers. It works FINE for static log filenames.

In case of dynamic file, it fails with `OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/tmp/log_2011_01_01_1310'`

Since first handle creates the dir, then control moves to the second module where `handler2` tries to create the dir and file again and fails, if I keep the handler the same how will it get the info of the previously created log file info?

The intention was:
**`handler1` will create the logfile and that will be used for logging for rest handlers, used in multiple modules.**

```
args = ('/var/tmp/log.file','a')
```

To make it dynamic I have used the solution of custom FileHandler.

```
[handler1]
level=DEBUG
formatter=client
class: logger.myFileHandler
args = ('/var/tmp','client.log','a')

[handler2]
level=DEBUG
formatter=server
class: logger.myFileHandler
args = ('/var/tmp','client.log','a')

#custom file handler class

class myFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self,path,fileName,mode):
        time = '2011_01_01_1310'  ##Will generate dynamically once in execution.  
        path = path+"/log_"+time
        os.mkdir(path)
        super(myFileHandler,self).__init__(path+"/"+fileName,mode)
```

Comment: And so your problem is... ?

Comment: Please use question marks for your questions. It makes things so much easier for people that would like to answer to know what your asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an existing directory with `os.mkdir`. But you do call it twice with the same parameter.

Either check whether the directory already exists prior to calling `os.mkdir` or catch the exception and ignore it:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != 17:
        raise
```

Other than that opening a file twice to append to it is fine.